# Onchange values wants to store at loading time..it is possible in wizard treeview?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, odoo

I want store the onchange data in wizard tree view because I have button in tree view,if I click that button the wizard gets closed...So I need to store the data while loading the values..The tree view contains one2many field.

It is possible.?